# Finding a keyword in a node and getting the node name in DOM

Tags: java, regex, dom, nodes, siblings

I want to search a DOM for a specific keyword, and when it is found, I want to know which Node in the tree it is from.

```
static void search(String segment, String keyword) {

    if (segment == null)
        return;

    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(keyword,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    StringBuffer test=new StringBuffer (segment);
    matcher=p.matcher(test);

    if(!matcher.hitEnd()){        
        total++;
        if(matcher.find())
        //what to do here to get the node?
    }
}

public static void traverse(Node node) {
    if (node == null || node.getNodeName() == null)
        return;

    search(node.getNodeValue(), "java");

    check(node.getFirstChild());

    System.out.println(node.getNodeValue() != null && 
                       node.getNodeValue().trim().length() == 0 ? "" : node);
    check(node.getNextSibling());
}
```

Comment: What language is this? It looks like Java or possibly c#, if you include the language in the question tags you will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: yes its java and thanks for your comment :)

Comment: I find quite hard understanding what you want to achieve but probably you want to return a boolean from search to indicate that the token has been found. If you specify better your goal it would be easier to help.

Comment: well, you are wrong, imagine i searched a dom for a keyword. when it been found, i want to know it belongs to which part of tree, the node, parent node and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) ([API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)):

```
// the XML & search term
String xml = "<foo>" + "<bar>" + "xml java xpath" + "</bar>" + "</foo>";
InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
final String term = "java";
// search expression and term variable resolver
String expression = "//*[contains(text(),$term)]";
final QName termVariableName = new QName("term");
class TermResolver implements XPathVariableResolver {
  @Override
  public Object resolveVariable(QName variableName) {
    return termVariableName.equals(variableName) ? term : null;
  }
}
// perform the search
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(new TermResolver());
Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, src, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

If you want to do more complex matching via regular expressions, you can provide your own [function resolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setXPathFunctionResolver%28javax.xml.xpath.XPathFunctionResolver%29).

Breakdown of the XPath expression `//*[contains(text(),$term)]`:

- `//*` the asterisk selects any element; the double-slash means any parent
- `[contains(text(),$term)]` is a predicate that matches the text
- `text()` is a function that gets the element's text
- `$term` is a variable; this can be used to resolve the term "java" via the variable resolver; a resolver is preferred to string concatenation to prevent injection attacks (similar to SQL injection issues)
- `contains(arg1,arg2)` is a function that returns true if arg1 contains arg2

`XPathConstants.NODE` tells the API to select a single node; you could use [`NODESET`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html#NODESET) to get all matches as a [`NodeList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html).

Comment: Introduction to XPath: [XML in a Nutshell: Chapter 9: XPath](http://oreilly.com/catalog/xmlnut/chapter/ch09.html). Java XPath tutorial: [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html)

Comment: wow, confusing, could you explain it at least for values that you set for variables?(for example the tags you declared and "term")

Comment: there is a problem yet,i customized your code with mine,sent the string as **node.getnodevalue** to the search function.as you can see in my code, it's **segment** variable.then i removed your two first line of your code cause already i declared them in my code and replaced**test** with **src** in last line of your code. it gives error**[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.** i can guess it ,ay occurs because of different type, but it also gives error for the fact that cant connect to the string,cause i parse html to dom tree, so what is the solution,if you dont mind to help :)

Comment: You can pass a `Document` directly to [XPath.evaluate(String,Object,QName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29) instead of using an `InputSource`.

Comment: im a bit confused, you used both Xpath.evaluate and Inputsource in your code, but you saying i can use xpath.evaluate instead of inputsource.

Comment: I am saying you can use a `Document` instead of `InputSource`

Comment: oh, you are right, i didnt read your last comment carefully, i did what u said, passed to the function an obj but it gives another error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UnSupported Return Type : term

Comment: though the argument type is string as term was delcared...so irritating :(

Comment: i must say you were right, when i added the Document directly it worked, i was doing sth wrong in the past and thats why gave me errors, anyway, thanks a zillion :)